# Find blocks of same values in a collection and manipulate surrounding values

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I really don't know how to summarize the question in the title, sorry. :)

Let's assume I have a collection (i.e. ObservableCollection) containing thousands of objects. These objects consist of an ascending timestamp and a `FALSE` boolean value (very simplified).

Like this:

```
[0] 0.01, FALSE
[1] 0.02, FALSE
[2] 0.03, FALSE
[3] 0.04, FALSE
...
```

Now, let's assume that within this collection, there are blocks that have their flag set to `TRUE`.

Like this:

```
[2345] 23.46, FALSE
[2346] 23.47, FALSE
[2347] 23.48, FALSE
[2348] 23.49, TRUE
[2349] 23.50, TRUE
[2350] 23.51, TRUE
[2351] 23.52, TRUE
[2352] 23.53, TRUE
[2353] 23.54, FALSE
[2354] 23.55, FALSE
...
```

I need to find the blocks and set all flags within 1.5 seconds before and after the block to `TRUE` aswell.
How can I achieve this while maintaining a reasonable performance?

Comment: can't you just at the moment someone sets the property to TRUE, immediately change surrounding objects properties to TRUE too ?

Comment: No, that's unfortunately not possible.

Comment: Why don't you use a reference in your surrounding objects to the boolean value of your collection instead of having private boolean property?

Comment: Condering that you have necesity of maintain constant timeing regardless the amount of elements in array (remaining in boundaries of acceptable) the best solution would be, imo, dictionary or any other key/value store, for constant O(1) pick performance. But you need construct that somehow.

Comment: I can't change the architecture of the object (I used a very simplified representation in my question, mind you), since it would mean a huge change in my software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a data structure like this:

**Edit:** Changed TimeStamp to `double`

```
public class Value
{
    public double TimeStamp { get; set; }

    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

And a list of this objects called `values`. Then you could search for active data sets and for each of them mark the values within a range around them as active:

```
double range = 1.5;
var activeTimeStamps = values.Where(value => value.IsActive)
                             .Select(value => value.TimeStamp)
                             .ToList();
foreach (var timeStamp in activeTimeStamps)
{
    var valuesToMakeActive =
        values.Where
            (
                value =>
                    value.TimeStamp >= timeStamp - range &&
                    value.TimeStamp <= timeStamp + range
            );
    foreach (var value in valuesToMakeActive)
    {
        value.IsActive = true;
    }
}
```

Anyway, I guess there will be a solution with better performance..

Comment: This might work. My timestamps are just double values, though. I'm gonna try this quick.

Comment: I changed the timestamp to double. The approach is the same.

Comment: Yep, this works. :) Not the fastest, but it's a start. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2):

Matthias G solution is correct, although quite slow – seems to have n-squared complexity.

First algo scans the input `values` to filter them by IsActive, retrieve timestamps and put into a new list - this is O(n), at least. Then it scans the constructed list, which may be in the worst case the whole input – O(n), and for every timestamp retrieved it scans input `values` to modify appropriate of them – O(n^2).
Then it builds additional list just to be scanned once and destroyed.

I'd propose a solution similar somewhat to mergesort. First scan input values and for each Active item push appropriate time interval into a queue. You may delay pushing to see if the next interval overlaps the current one – then extend the interval instead of push. When the input list is done, finally push the last delayed interval. This way your queue will contain the (almost) minimum number of time intervals you want to modify.

Then scan again the `values` data and compare timestamps to the first interval in a queue. If the item's timestamp falls into the current interval, mark the item Active. If it falls past the interval remove the interval from the queue and compare the timestamp to the next one – and so on, until the item is in or before the interval. Your input data are in chronological order, so the intervals will be in the same order, too. This allows accomplishing the task in a single parallel pass through both lists.

Comment: Another approach would be simple by scanning the whole vector twice. First scan upwards, catching a timestamp of each Active item and mark Active every item which is at most `margin` later than the timestamp caught. Then scan downwards, catching timestamp for every Active item and mark Active every item which is at most `margin` earlier than the timestamp caught. Done. And no additional lists or any other data structures.